How can I play a Musical Note using NAudio (Or Otherwise) in C#?
I Nugetted NAudio for Winforms. Does anybody have an example of how to play a note using NAudio (or by some other means)? I would hope it'd be something easy similar to:
NAudio.PlayNote(28, 100); // 28 == 41.203 == Open E String on a bass

...with the first arg being the Midi number of a note and the second the count of milliseconds to play it.
I realize it's probably not that simple, though; can somebody point me in the right direction?
UPDATE
When I try to use NAudio.Midi, as suggested below, I get this in the using clause:

...and this when trying to call that method in the code:

UPDATE 2
Here's the error I get when I try to add the using:

...and here's the package in my solution (it is Winforms); am I missing my step, or something?

UPDATE 3
Do I need to install more packages? When I open Manage NuGet Packages, it shows NAudio.WinForms as installed, but there are also a few "Transitive Packages" (6). Do I need to install these (MS and NAudio) packages, too?
UPDATE 4
In the Package Manager console, I entered Install-Package NAudio and it seemed to work. I'll czech out the code in the answer tomorrow...
UPDATE 5
I'm getting error messages "The type or namespace name 'NoteOffEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
This is my relevant code:
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using NAudio.Midi;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace EarTrainingAndCreativityForBassGtr_VS2022
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int NoteToPlay = 0;
        int wrongGuesses = 0;

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer noteOffTimer;
        private MidiOut midiOut;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            midiOut = new MidiOut(0);
            noteOffTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            noteOffTimer.Tick += NoteOffTimer_Tick;
        }

        private void PlayMidiNote(int note, int velocity, int duration)
        {
            var noteOn = new NoteOnEvent(0, 1, note, velocity, 0);
            midiOut.Send(noteOn.GetAsShortMessage());

            noteOffTimer.Interval = duration;
            noteOffTimer.Start();
        }

        private void NoteOffTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            noteOffTimer.Stop();
            var noteOff = new NoteOffEvent(0, 1, 28, 100, 0);
            midiOut.Send(noteOff.GetAsShortMessage());
        }

        private void btnPlayNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearPreviousVals();
            btnPlayNote.Enabled = false;
            int[] randomNotes = GetFourRandomNumbers(28, 67);
            NoteToPlay = randomNotes[0];

            // now play that note
            using (var midiOut = new MidiOut(0)) // 0 is the device number, adjust as needed
            {
                // Send a NoteOn event to start the note
                var noteOn = new NoteOnEvent(0, 1, NoteToPlay, 100, 0); // channel 1,               NoteToPlay, velocity 100, at time 0
                midiOut.Send(noteOn.GetAsShortMessage());

                // Wait for the duration of the note
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
                System.Windows.Forms.

                // Send a NoteOff event to stop the note
                var noteOff = new NoteOffEvent(0, 1, 28, 100, 0); // channel 1, note 28,            velocity 100, at time 0
                midiOut.Send(noteOff.GetAsShortMessage());
            }
            radbtn1.Checked = false;
            radBtn2.Checked = false;
            radbtn3.Checked = false;
            radbtn4.Checked = false;
        }

        private void ClearPreviousVals()
        {
            radbtn1.Text = "Note 1";
            radbtn1.Tag = null;
            //rest elided
        }

        private string ConvertNoteNumberToNoteName(int noteToPlay)
        {
            if (noteToPlay == 28) return "E1";
        // .... elided
            else return "Bad arg to ConvertNoteNumberToNoteName() — not within the expected bounds";
        }

        private int[] GetFourRandomNumbers(int LowestVal, int HighestVal)
        {
            // elided
        }

        private void radbtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radbtn1.Tag == null) return;
            bool correctChoice = NoteToPlay.ToString() == radbtn1.Tag.ToString(); 
            if (correctChoice)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Correct! You chose the correct note after " +                  wrongGuesses.ToString() + " incorrect choices!");
                btnPlayNote.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                wrongGuesses = wrongGuesses + 1;
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong choice. Try again.");
            };
        }

        private void radBtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // elided
        }

        private void radbtn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // elided
        }

        private void radbtn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // elided
        }
    }
}

Also, for this line of code:
var noteOff = new NoteOffEvent(0, 1, 28, 100, 0);

I'm getting "The type or namespace name 'var' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
UPDATE 6
My app is targeting .NET framework 8:

NoteOffset is missing from the NAudio.Midi list:

UPDATE 7
I got the run-time exception "already allocated using MidiOutOpen" on this line:
    // now play that note
    using (var midiOut = new MidiOut(0)) 
    {

So I commented out the initialization of MidiOut in the form's constructor:
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //midiOut = new MidiOut(0);
    noteOffTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    noteOffTimer.Tick += NoteOffTimer_Tick;
}

Here's the code in some context:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int NoteToPlay = 0;
    int wrongGuesses = 0;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer noteOffTimer;
    private MidiOut midiOut;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //midiOut = new MidiOut(0); <-- commented out after exception
            noteOffTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            noteOffTimer.Tick += NoteOffTimer_Tick;
        }
    
    . . .

    private void btnPlayNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ClearPreviousVals();
            btnPlayNote.Enabled = false;
            int[] randomNotes = GetFourRandomNumbers(28, 67);
        NoteToPlay = randomNotes[0];

        // now play that note // exception: "already allocated using MidiOutOpen"
        using (var midiOut = new MidiOut(0)) // 0 is the device number, adjust as needed
        {
                var noteOn = new NoteOnEvent(0, 1, NoteToPlay, 100, 0); 
                midiOut.Send(noteOn.GetAsShortMessage());
                var noteOff = new NoteOnEvent(0, 1, NoteToPlay, 0, 0); 
                midiOut.Send(noteOff.GetAsShortMessage());
            }
    

So commenting out the line in the form's constructor prevented the exception from occurring, but I still hear no note being played.

var noteOnEvent = new NoteOnEvent(0, channel, noteNumber, 100, 50); and then midiOut.Send(noteOnEvent.GetAsShortMessage());. There is an example here.

I added a "using NAudio" to the .cs file, but get the err msgs "The type or namespace name 'NoteOnEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
with the code shown above. Besides, the linked article is about sending events; I just want a simple call to "Play this note" and provide the frequency and perhaps the volume and duration. Surely there's a way to do that without having to jump through hoops. Otherwise, I'll record the notes as .wav files, save them as project resources, and play them that way. That seems quite tedious/unnecessary, though.

try using NAudio.Midi;

See my update; doesn't seem available. I installed the Nuget.Winforms package...???

should be available in this version https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/2.2.1

If you prefer to go with wav solution, it is var device = new WaveOutEvent(); var audio = new AudioFileReader(@"C:\example.wav"); device.Init(audio); device.Play(); This requires using NAudio.Wave; To stop playing it's: device.Stop();

Thanks; I might eventually go that route, if necessary, but would prefer to use the MIDI numbered notes (28 for low open bass E string, etc.)
